# Route template in external file?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

In a C# MVC project i am using VUE in a small section of the site.

I have setup a rellay simple solution with vuejs and vue-router.
I wish to have my template file in an external, either .vue or .html file, that i can call, instead of having the template inline in my script. But how do i do this?

Page HTML

```
<router-link to="/foo">Go to Foo</router-link>
<router-link to="/bar">Go to Bar</router-link>    
<router-view></router-view>
```

Vue script:

```
const Foo = { path: 'mytemplate.html' }
    const Bar = { template: '<div>bar</div>' }
    const routes = [
        { path: '/foo', component: Foo },
        { path: '/bar', component: Bar }
    ]

    const router = new VueRouter({
        routes
    })

    var vm = new Vue({
        router
    })
```

`path: 'mytemplate.html'` does not work. Any other ways of doing this?

Comment: It's not currently possible.  See [this explanation](https://vuejs.org/2015/10/28/why-no-template-url) by Vue's author for more detail.

Comment: Think in components, not templates!